# How to print the file name by calling a function name in the file in python

Tags: python, call

Here is a program based on CV screening. In this program I have given scoring for each CV to rank them. Now the output just gives me the scoring number I want in the output that it gives me the file name.
The program is:

```
import re
import fitz
import os

# Create an array "zs[]" that store the score values
zs = []

# call the Resume files by calling the folder name
for filename in os.listdir('resume/'):

    # Select only PDF files
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        print(filename)
        os.chdir('C:/Users/M. Abrar Hussain/Desktop/cv/resume')
        pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')

        # Extract the text Data from resume files
        with fitz.open(pdfFileObj) as doc:
            text = ""
            for page in doc:
                text += page.getText()
            print(text)

            # Splitting the Resume Data into many indexes of Array
            p = doc.loadPage(0)
            p_text = p.getText()
            p_lines = p_text.splitlines()

            # Split the information and the data
            split_lst = [i.split(': ', 1) for i in p_lines]
            d = {a: b.rstrip() for a, b in split_lst}

            # Naming the information part
            f = d["Name"]
            g = d["GPA"]
            h = d["Skills"]
            i = d["Experience"]
            p = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", i)

            # search the keywords with the data that extract from resume
            search_keywords = ['Laravel', 'Java', 'Python']
            search_exp = ['1', '1.5', '2', '2.5', '3']
            search_gpa = ['2.5', '2.6', '2.7', '2.8', '2.9', '3.0', '3.1', '3.2', '3.3', '3.4', '3.5', '3.6', '3.7',
                          '3.8', '3.9', '4.0']

            # Comparing GPA data with the keywords
            lst = []
            for gpa in search_gpa:
                if gpa in g:
                    lst.append(gpa)

            # Comparing Skills data with keywords
            lst1 = []
            for word in search_keywords:
                if word in h:
                    lst1.append(word)

            # Comparing Experience data with keywords
            lst2 = []
            for exp in search_exp:
                if exp in p:
                    lst2.append(exp)

            # Scoring the Extracted data to see the best resume
            score = 0
            w1 = []

            # Scoring the GPA
            for w1 in lst:
                if '3.0' <= w1 < '3.5':
                    score += 1
                if '3.5' <= w1 <= '4':
                    score += 2

            # Scoring the SKills
            for w1 in lst1:
                if w1 == 'Laravel':
                    score += 2
                if w1 == 'Python':
                    score += 2
                if w1 == 'Java':
                    score += 1

            # Scoring the Experience
            for w1 in lst2:
                if '2.5' <= w1 < '3':
                    score += 0.5
                if '3' <= w1 < '3.5':
                    score += 1
                if '3.5' <= w1:
                    score += 2

            # store score values in an array
            tt = zs.append(score)

            print("%s has Scored %s" % (f, score))
            print('\n')

            pdfFileObj.close()

# Rank the CV's on the basis of Scoring
zs.sort(reverse=True)
print(zs)
```

The Output of the program is:

```
cv2.pdf
Name: Danish Ejaz  
GPA: 3.7  
Skills: Python, Java  
Experience: 2.5 years 

Danish Ejaz has Scored 5.5


cv3.pdf
Name: Abdullah  
GPA: 3.2  
Skills: Laravel, Java  
Experience: 2 years 

Abdullah has Scored 4


cv5.pdf
Name: M. Abrar Hussain  
GPA: 3.5  
Skills: Python, Laravel  
Experience: 3 years 

M. Abrar Hussain has Scored 7


[7, 5.5, 4]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The second last line is the result after scoring. In this result it just gives us the scoring number, can I call the file name in the result as well? if yes then kindly help me to complete this project.

Comment: You would like to open the best pdf file in some viewer?

Comment: can you post what exactly you expect as expected output?

Comment: @RomanPavelka Yes the scoring is based on experience, Skills, and GPA.

Comment: @ignoring_gravity [7, 5.5, 4] This is the output of the program a I want the filename with this just like that [7 cv5.pdf, 5.5 cv2.pdf, 4 cv3.pdf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way IMHO is to define a class, minimal variant would be

```py
class Candidate:
    def __init__(self, name, score, filename):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
        self.filename = filename

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.score > other.score

    def __str__(self):
       return f'Candidate{self.name, self.filename, self.score}' 

    def __repr__(self):
       return self.__str__()
```

put this before your main `for` loop. Then instead of

```py
            tt = zs.append(score)
```

put

```py
            tt = zs.append(Candidate(f, score, filename))
```

It should work the same otherwise. Here is little explanatory usage:

```py
class Candidate:
    def __init__(self, name, score, filename):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
        self.filename = filename

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.score > other.score

    def __str__(self):
       return f'Candidate{self.name, self.filename, self.score}'

    def __repr__(self):
       return self.__str__()

# __init__ allows this
a = Candidate("Arnold", 10, "arnold.pdf")
b = Candidate("Betty", 11, "betty.pdf")

# __gt__ allows this
print(a < b)
print(a > b)

# __str__ allows this
print(a)

# __repr__ allows human-readable this
print([a, b])

# __repr__ and __gt__ allows human-readable this
print(sorted([b, a]))
```

This would print

```
True
False
Candidate('Arnold', 'arnold.pdf', 10)
[Candidate('Arnold', 'arnold.pdf', 10), Candidate('Betty', 'betty.pdf', 11)]
[Candidate('Arnold', 'arnold.pdf', 10), Candidate('Betty', 'betty.pdf', 11)]
```

Comment: The Output is:  " [<__main__.Candidate object at 0x000001990DA62D30>, <__main__.Candidate object at 0x000001990F5AACA0>, <__main__.Candidate object at 0x000001990DA62DF0>] "

Comment: @AbrarHussain yay, right, we need also `__repr__(self)` function, I have fixed my post now

Comment: yeh that right, but one thing is that the score is not an integer value it's a float value. In this output it just shows an integer.

Comment: Allright, now it should work with any comparable score...

Comment: You are welcome! Well, I have learned something as well :)

Comment: Creating a class for this is a lot of overhead, IMO. But for sure: this works ;)

Comment: @Rafael-WO well, it is several lines more, but IMHO in this case it makes stuff more readable. I would also separate data extraction and score compuation to separate functions, put them to separate files and you would have very short clean main file...

Answer (score 1):

You just have to store your filenames and print them at the end together with the scores:

```py
# Create a dictionary with filenames as key and add the score as value
# Note that this might be an issue if you have irrelevant files in your directory
file_scores = dict.fromkeys(listdir('resume/'))

# call the Resume files by calling the folder name
for filename in file_scores:
    # Your scoring logic
    (...)

    # store score values in the dictionary
    file_scores[filename] = score

    (...)


# Remove items without value
file_scores = {k: v for k, v in file_scores.items() if v}

# Sort the dictionary based on score descending
file_scores = {k: v for k, v in sorted(file_scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)}

# Print the file and the score together
for filename, score in file_scores.items():
    if score:  # Ignore other files
        print(f"File {filename}: Score = {score}")
```

Comment: This won't work as it breaks the link between file-name and score. zs is in a different order as files.

Comment: @CHecht Ah you are totally right! I will fix it.

Comment: @CHecht I guess I fixed it :)

Comment: @Rafael-WO it gives me error:                                                                              
  " Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\M. Abrar Hussain\Desktop\cv\difflib.py", line 108, in <module>
    file_scores = {k: v for k, v in sorted(file_scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)}
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType' "

Comment: @AbrarHussain I added an additional line which fixes this error. You basically have to remove all items with value `None` first.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is by using table-structures. Given that you have similar fields in each result, you could for instance create a [pd.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) that you fill with all your values and then afterwards use [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and select the score column.

There are of course other alternatives where you use [np.argsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) or similar, but a DataFrame is probably the easiest way to achieve what you are after.